# Virtualbox 5.1.2 does not accept microphone input to Windows 7 guest

Tags: windows, virtualbox, audio, drivers, microphone

My host OS is Windows 10 64-bit, with Realtek/Intel audio drivers. I'm trying to get my microphone to work in my Windows 7 (64-bit) guest, but it's not working. My current configuration is AC'97.

When I have it set to Intel HD Audio (default setting), no recording devices are listed. But when I have it set to ICH AC'97, this is what the list looks like:

Microphone, CD Player, Line In (selected, default), Aux, Mono Mix, Phone Line, Stereo Mix

But when I start speaking, the audio meter doesn't move on any of the devices that I set as default, despite the "line in" setting being the most recommended.
Here are the list of recording devices on my host:

Microphone (AnvSoft), MIDI (AnvSoft), Microphone (Realtek) (default, selected), Stereo Mix (Realtek).

And the guest drivers are already up to date, but still no microphone input. The audio playback (output) still works perfectly, but the input (microphone) is the only issue.

Comment: Can anyone answer?